# If condition giving error message

Tags: php

The below mentioned code s working fine on 5.3.17 and I have php 5.3.27 and the issue is i have to make this code work on 5.3.27

LINK to full code: http://www.videobluemoon.com/secure/add.txt

```
$customer_id = (int)$_REQUEST['customer_id'];

if($customer_id  => 0 ) {
           $query = $query.','.$_REQUEST['customer_id'];
   } else {
           die('cust id: '. $_REQUEST['customer_id']);
           die('Please use your browser\'s back button to ensure you have selected a customer');
   }

   if($customer_id => 0 ) {
           $query = $query.', '.$_REQUEST['sysuser_id'];
   else
           die ('There was a problem with the system user');
```

Comment: Still dont get the two dies in else , you will never see the second die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **`==`** instead of **`=>`**

**`=>`** is used to access key-value pairs of an array whereas **`==`** is used for comparison operations.

```
<?php
$customer_id = (int)$_REQUEST['customer_id'];

if ( $customer_id  == 0 ){
$query = $query . ',' . $_REQUEST['customer_id'] . "";
}else{
die( 'cust id: ' . $_REQUEST['customer_id']);
die ( 'Please use your browser\'s back button to ensure you have selected a customer' );
}

if ( $customer_id  > 0 ){
$query = $query . ', ' . $_REQUEST['sysuser_id'] .  "";
}
else
{
die ( 'There was a problem with the system user' );
}
```

Comment: unexpected T_ELSE on line no xxx

   if ( $customer_id  => 0 ){
           $query = $query . ', ' . $_REQUEST['sysuser_id'] .  "";

   else --------------------------------ERROR on this LINE

           die ( 'There was a problem with the system user' );

Answer (score 6):

there isnt anything like `=>`

if you want to check greater than equal to than use `>=`

```
if ( $customer_id  >= 0 ){
```

and for less than equal to use `>=`
and `==` is for equal to equal to

check this [**Comparison Operators ¶**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

`=>` it should be `>=` but your code will be look like

```
    $customer_id = (int)$_REQUEST['customer_id'];

        if ( $customer_id  == 0 ){
                   $query = $query . ',' . $_REQUEST['customer_id'] . "";
           }else{
                   die( 'cust id: ' . $_REQUEST['customer_id']);
                   die ( 'Please use your browser\'s back button to ensure you have selected a customer' );
           }

           if ( $customer_id  > 0 ){
                   $query = $query . ', ' . $_REQUEST['sysuser_id'] .  "";
           } else {
                   die ( 'There was a problem with the system user' );
           }
```